# How to get list of Output Cached Objects in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'm trying to get list of cached objects in my application. 
In this page [MSDN - Cache Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) it says that I can use getEnumerator() function of the cache class to get list of cached objects. but when I use it, it only returns a Dictionary of cached objects like bundles etc, and there is no item from my output caches.

Comment: How did you use it? Post your code.

Comment: IDictionaryEnumerator CacheEnum = Cache.GetEnumerator();
while (CacheEnum.MoveNext())
{
  cacheItem = Server.HtmlEncode(CacheEnum.Current.ToString()); 
  Response.Write(cacheItem);
}

Comment: Post your code in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: By the way, `GetEnumertor()` doesn't return a Dictionary, it returns an `IEnumerator`. You are assigning it to an `IDictionaryEnumerator` in your code.